# How to get all products from Shopify REST API - Flutter/Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, shopify, shopify-api

I'm trying to fetch all products from Shopify REST API. By default, product endpoint returns only 250 products. I dig into the documentation and found out that the product endpoint also returns header response which contains link to the next page

https://shopify.dev/api/usage/pagination-rest

For now, I able to fetch the first 250 products and page_info parameter value that is used to navigate to the next link

```
List<ProductModel> productList = [];

  void fetchProducts() async {
    Uri url = Uri.parse("example.myshopify.com/admin/api/2022-01/products.json?limit=250");
    final response = await http.get(url);
    final responseHeader = response.headers;
    String? headerLink = responseHeader['link']; // it contains page_info parameter that help us to navigate to next value, how to make use of it to fetch all products and add it inside productList (List)

    final responseBody = jsonDecode(response.body);
    List<dynamic> products = responseBody["products"] as List<dynamic>;
    List<ProductModel> tempList = [];

    for(var product in products){
      ProductModel productModel = ProductModel.fromMap(product);
      tempList.add(productModel);
    }

      productList = tempList;
      isLoading = false;
      notifyListeners();
  }
```

Comment: You should think abstractly. Imagine that this information is on your computer disk, in files, 250 (or less) records in each file, and you need to collect everything from all these files into one list. It seems to me that this is an easy task. You have the same case, but only "files" are located remotely. Based on the fact that your (abstract) algorithms do not care where to get this information from and everything will work for you.